# What is this 3 word phrase?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

If I say

> " 1   2   3"
>
> You might thank me politely.

But if I

> " 1   2   3"
>
> You might scream loudly

If I bowl

> " 2   3   1"
>
> You might cut it squarely

What are the three words 1,2 and 3?

Comment: are the first and second both meant to be 1 2 3?

Comment: Yes they are meant to be same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the phrase

> Break a leg

Say

> "break a leg" to wish good luck, being thanked politely perhaps

Do

> "break a leg" and someone may scream loudly.

and Bowl

> a leg break is a cricket term, after which the batter may cut it squarely

Comment: Very good and very fast.

Comment: @RogerA Welcome to Puzzling SE! Just so you know, you can always mark the correct answer as correct by [accepting](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it.